# Chown mounted volume in boot2docker osx

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Specifically what I am trying to do is to run the official mongodb docker image using boot2docker in osx.

https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/tree/master

I am aware that I can change the docker file to run everything as root instead of gosu and it would work.

But I really need mount /Users in such a way that you can chown and chomd freely from within boot2docker and run the official image as is.

I have tried a few script like https://gist.github.com/olalonde/3f7512c0bd2bc8abb46d

but to no avail, I still cannot ssh inside boot2docker and for example sudo chown 1000:1000 mdata

All I would get is

chown: mdata: Operation not permitted

chmod: mdata: Permission denied

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Well, I  think it's a current limitation of the virtualbox shared folders (boot2docker is based on virtualbox).

Comment: I see...so this may be impossible then?

Comment: For now yeah.. your best bet would be to use a linux machine or set up a vm with docker inside and your files too (and share the files from the vm to your host using nfs or something.. but I'm just thinking out loud here.. :-))